# How do I un-crop my desktop in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, display

All of a sudden I see that my icons have been cropped off from my desktop. Their visibility has gone.

[image: Desktop Icon Screenshot]

(please ignore those black marks, sorry).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to [refresh the desktop](https://s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/windows/711325280.jpg)?

Comment: Have you tried the [show desktop button](http://windows.intowindows.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/remove-show-desktop-button-from-windows-10-taskbar-pic1_thumb.jpg)?

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob tried both. no change

Comment: What about a restart? Or [reorder the icons](http://cdn.winability.com/info/desktop-icons-auto-arrange.png) options?

Comment: Since when do you have this problem? Have you installed something? Have you updated your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple screen lock and unlock will solve your problem. Once you sign off, re-login to Windows and this will make the screen normal.